# 2 dimenssion C# string array to js

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, json, javascriptserializer

I want to send a C# 2 dimenssions string array to my JS client page.

server:

```
string[,] info = ib.GetInfo();
//info is [["string1","string2","string3"],["string4","string5","string6"]]

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();           
return this.Content((new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(info), "text/javascript");
```

ON the client JS side:

```
var mysr= JSON.parse(resp );
```

"string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6"

The result mysr is a 1 dimenssion array!

What is wrong? any help would be appreciated. The string can also contain quotes and double quotes

Comment: `JSON.parse` should be able to handle a 2-dimensional array without issue. I believe the problem lies in `JavaScriptSerializer` converting it to a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: Can you post how looks resp value on client?

Comment: I agree with @nderscore, this does sound like a problem with the way it is serialised. Can you verify that `id.GetInfo();` returns `string[,]` and not `string[][]`. You'd most likely get an exception if this weren't the case, but just as a sanity check... Also, try to create a nested loop to convert `string[,]` into `string[][]` and try to serialise that, just to see what happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way how JavaScriptSerializer works. See these codes

```
string[,] info1 = new string[2,3]{{"string1","string2","string3"},
                                  {"string4","string5","string6"}};
var json1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(info1);
```

**json =>** `["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6"]`

```
string[][] info2 = new string[][] { new[]{ "string1", "string2", "string3" }, 
                                    new[]{ "string4", "string5", "string6" } };
var json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(info2);
```

**json =>** `[["string1","string2","string3"],["string4","string5","string6"]]`

if you can't change the return type of the method `GetInfo()`. I would suggest to use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info1);
```

It will return the json string as you expect.

Comment: I was typing my answer suggesting (trying) converting `string[,]` into `string[][]` when you posted this. Perfect timing :)

Comment: Indeed, i realized that [,] was wrong for JSON. Everything works as expected now. thanks so much! I just had to changed the return type of getinfo(). on JS client I still use JSON.parse(), eval works too.

Answer (score 0):

A multidimensional array is serialized as a one-dimensional array.  You can use a jagged array instead of a two-dimensional array

You can also use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/08/06/json-net-4-5-release-8-multidimensional-array-support-unicode-improvements).  Json.NET 4.5 Release 8 supports multidimensional arrays.